# Why IDA* Is Faster Than A* But Why IDA* Visit More Nodes That A*?

Tags: algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence

I used ida* for 8 puzzle and my friends used a* for it too ( with same manhattan distance huristic ).

I calculate average of my algorithm for 20 examples and my friend's algorithm , The time average for my algorithm was very faster than my friend's algorithm but mine average nodes that visited is alot more than my friend's.

How is that possible? Can someone explain me where i didn't understand.

This is my search algorithm

```
public Set<String> ida(Node startNode) {
        visitedNodes.clear();
        Node initNode = startNode;
        int fValueMin;
        /*fValueMin depth to run the program.
        IDA* method being called iteratively until the depth reaches*/
        for (fValueMin = initNode.getfValue(); fValueMin < 100; fValueMin++) {
            visitedNodes.clear();
            pathNodes.clear();
            // Depth First search 
            Node nextNode = dfs(startNode, fValueMin, visitedNodes);
            /*Verifying the returned is goal state or not. If it is goal the goal exit loop*/
            if (nextNode != null && nextNode.equals(CommonConstants.goalState)) {
                System.out.println("Goal state Found");
                System.out.println("Nodes Visited:" + visited);
                return pathNodes.keySet();
            }
            // System.out.println("Iteration:" + fValueMin);
        }
        System.out.println("Number of Nodes Visited:" + visited);
        return null;
    }
```

This is my friend's search algorithm

```
private ActionSequence AStar(){
        System.out.println("AStar Search Started"); 
        boolean find=false; 
        QNode current; 

        do{
            current=queue.removeFirst(); 
            if(queue.size%1==0){
                try{
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out),"ASCII"), 32);

                    out.write("*********************************************************************************\n\n");
                    out.write("Queue: "+queue.size+"    Depth: "+(current.element.depth+1)+"   price: "+(current.price));
                    out.write(printState(current.element.state)); 
                    out.write("\n\n\n");

                    out.flush();
                    //out.close();
            }catch(IOException gg){}
            }

            if(problem.Goal_Test(current.element.state)){
                find=true; 
            }else{
                if(current.element.action!='d'){

                        PSTNode up_child=Expand(current.element,'u'); 
                        if(up_child.state[11]==1){
                            tree.addNodeUp(up_child,  current.element);
                            QNode up_child_qn= new QNode(up_child,null, null);
                            queue.addSort(up_child_qn);
                        }

                }

                if(current.element.action!='u'){

                        PSTNode down_child=Expand(current.element,'d');
                        if(down_child.state[11]==1){
                            tree.addNodeDown(down_child,  current.element);
                            QNode down_child_qn= new QNode(down_child,null, null);
                            queue.addSort(down_child_qn);
                        }

                }

                if(current.element.action!='r'){

                        PSTNode left_child=Expand(current.element,'l');
                        if(left_child.state[11]==1){
                            tree.addNodeLeft(left_child,  current.element);
                            QNode left_child_qn=new QNode(left_child,null, null);
                            queue.addSort(left_child_qn);
                        }

                }


                if(current.element.action!='l'){

                        PSTNode right_child=Expand(current.element,'r');
                        if(right_child.state[11]==1){
                            tree.addNodeRight(right_child,  current.element);
                            QNode right_child_qn= new QNode(right_child,null, null);
                            queue.addSort(right_child_qn);
                        }

                }
            }


        }while(!find); 
        System.out.println("*******************************founded*******************************************\n\n");             
            System.out.println("Queue: "+queue.size+"    Depth: "+(current.element.depth+1)); 
            System.out.println(printState(current.element.state)); 
            System.out.println("\n\n\n");

        return Path2Root(current.element); 
    }
```

Comment: Clearly, your implementation explores more nodes per unit of time. Without showing us the code of both implementations, we won't be able to say more than that.

Comment: @kaya3 I edited my answer but i think my problem is the working of Ida* .

Comment: Neither of these is reproducible; they both depend on variables (e.g. `visitedNodes`, `queue`) and methods which aren't declared here.

Comment: @kaya3 I know cause I should declare all variables that can't be done here , but is ida* visit more nodes than a*? if it visits more node why it is faster.

Comment: If your question is not about an individual implementation but the algorithms as a whole, there's a separate Stack Exchange site for theoretical computer science, [cs.se]; SO tries to stay grounded in specific details, with questions that are narrow and focused on well-defined problems.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your help , I didn't know that .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDA* iteratively opens the search frontier, so many nodes will be visited more than once. Whereas A* is more on the BFS side, depending on the implementation, most likely you will visit each node in the searched area only once. That is why IDA* visits more nodes than A*. In terms of running time, A* needs some priority queue to steer the search, the NLogN complexity is right there.

Comment: In your explanation i understand IDA* visit each node more than one , but the second part about being faster , I don't understand exactly why it is faster than A*

Comment: In A*, there should be a priority queue, used to maintain which node to expand first in next level of search tree construction. Each time when you push something to the Queue, there is LogN time needed to make sure the priority queue is valid (heap property). Theoretically, both algorithms should have same running time complexity. In practice, the DFS based (IDA*) algorithm may perform better due the implementations, locality of the cache.

Comment: Thanks about your explenation.

Comment: Could you provide resource for leaning IDA*? I prefer pseudo-code and I don't want recursive version. I need this to understand how it words...